# How to change icon on jlabel when an option (Bridal Gowns, Tuxedo) is selected

Tags: java, mysql, netbeans

I am making a gown rental system and I want to display the picture whenever they select a specific occasion like (Wedding, Bridal Party, Cocktail party etc.) and there are list of items under on it.

Here I just wanted to display all the product name in jcombobox and whenever they choose and item in jcombobox a picture will display that I saved in my product_Barong Table.

```
Connection c = Connector.ConnectDB();  
try {
   String sql = "Select * From rental.product_barong" ;
   pst = c.prepareStatement(sql);
   rs = pst.executeQuery();
   while(rs.next()){       
      String item = rs.getString("ItemName") ; 
      itemcombo.addItem(item); 
      String list = itemcombo.getSelectedItem()+ " " ;  
      String sql2 = "Select Image from rental.product_barong WHERE ItemName = ? ";
      pst = c.prepareStatement(sql2);              
      pst.setString(1, list);
      pst.executeQuery();

      byte[] img = rs.getBytes("Image") ;
      ImageIcon image = new ImageIcon(img);
      Image im = image.getImage();
      Image myimg = im.getScaledInstance(Picture.getWidth(), 
      Picture.getHeight(), Image.SCALE_SMOOTH) ;
      ImageIcon imgicn = new ImageIcon(myimg) ;
      Picture.setIcon(imgicn);

      }           
  }
catch(Exception e){
  JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
}
```

Comment: nice question but what problem with this code?

Comment: What is your specific question/problem?

Comment: It will display all the ITEM name from the table but i want that when i will choose an item in jcombobox the jlabel (picture) will change . that code is really really wrong hahaha i just dont know what to do with it .

Comment: Adding picture is my problem in short